# How to parse optional and named arguments into list and dict?

Tags: python, parsing

I would like a compact way to parse one-line strings that start with mandatory list-elements (unspecified number) and ends with dictionary-like definitions using `=`.

- The **element-separator** should be `,` and *spaces* should become part of the element -- which rules out `shlex`, I think.
- **Spaces** should/may be stripped at the **start and end** (quotes, too)
- If an element would contain a `,` the user is required to **quote with `"`**

  - either `"key=value,with,comma"`
  - or `key="value,with,comma"` -- whatever is easier to implement
- It's ok to have undefined behavior with **wrong quoting** or with elements containing a quote-char.
- Behaviour with **double keys** is also undefined.
- Slight variations of this are ok if it simplifies the implementation a lot.

Lets call the function `opts` and have it return a `list` and a `dict`,

Here are some input examples and desired results:

```
opts('dog,cat')                 # -> ["dog", "cat"], {}
opts('big fish,cat')            # -> ["big fish", "cat"], {}
opts('"a dog, a cat",a fish')   # -> ["a dog, a cat", "a fish"], {}
opts('key=value')               # -> [] {'key':'value'}
opts('key=the value,x=y')       # -> [] {'key':'the value', 'x':'y'}
opts('dog, big fish, eats="any, but peas", flies = no! '
   # -> ['dog','big fish'], {'eats':'any, but peas', 'flies':'no!' }
```

I disregarded `shlex`, `argparse`, `optparse` and  `configparser`, I can't see how I should do it with those. I am not sure if *Regular Expressions* crack this nut, though. `json` is a bit too strict with the syntax, I think. As is `eval`, if a bit more to my liking (because it parses python ;-))

My manual solution in `macro` is not very flexible and I would like to have its parameter handling be replaced by the more general `opts(s)` function described above:

```
def macro(s):
    kw = { 'see':u"\\see", 'type':u"Chapter", 'title': u'??' }
    params = s.split(",")
    kw['label'] = params[0]
    if len(params) > 1:                   # very inflexible
        kw['title'] = params[1]
    for param in params[2:]:              # wrong if p[1] is already key=value
        key, value = param.split("=",1)  # doesn't handle anything, too simple
        kw[key] = value
    # ...rest of code...
```

The goal is to have the reusable function `opts` to be used here:

```
def macro_see(s):
    ls, kw = opts(s)
    # ...rest of code...
```

Comment: You say the element separator should be `,` but your third example seems to suggest that `;` should also be a separator.

Comment: @DSM Oops. Leftover from my own tries. Corrected. Thx

Comment: It anyone wants to see how I integrated the proposed solutions and some demos, I put them on http://pastebin.com/BnyC48yH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, `opts` is essentially the same as yuvi's (with the added `strip`).  The splitter is a customization of `shlex`, using `posix` mode to handle quotes.

```
def mylex(x):
    lex = shlex.shlex(x, posix=True)
    lex.whitespace = ','
    lex.whitespace_split = True
    return list(lex)

def opts(x):
    ll = []
    dd = {}
    items = mylex(x)
    for item in items:
        if '=' in item:
            k, v = item.split('=',1)
            dd[k.strip(' "')] = v.strip(' "')
        else:
            ll.append(item.strip(' "'))
    return (ll,dd)
```

It passes:

```
trials = [
    ['dog,cat',(["dog", "cat"], {})],
    ['big fish,cat',(["big fish", "cat"], {})],
    ['"a dog, a cat",a fish',(["a dog, a cat", "a fish"], {})],
    ['key=value',([], {'key':'value'})],
    ['key=the value,x=y',([], {'key':'the value', 'x':'y'})],
    ['dog, big fish, eats="any, but peas", flies = no!',(['dog','big fish'], {'eats':'any, but peas', 'flies':'no!' })],
]
for (x,y) in trials:
    print('%r'%x)
    args = opts(x)
    print(args)
    if args != y:
        print('error, %r'%y)
    print('')
```

Comment: That is neat. It does not require preprocessing and does not need slow/dangerous eval. I will try it out.

Comment: Advantage of this over the `shlex`-solution: easier to understand and to maintain. Disadvantage: probably more difficult to tweak, because `shlex` is so inflexible -- but maybe not, I can always preprocess with `re` like with the `eval` solution, and modify the `lexer`. I will try it and see how it does over time.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to create your own split function, with a flag that toggles when " are introduced. Something like this:

```
def my_split(string, deli):
    res = []
    flag = True
    start = 0

    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        if c == '"':
            if flag:
                flag = False
            else:
                flag = True

        if c == deli and flag:
            res.append(string[start:i])
            start = i+1

    res.append(string[start:])
    return res
```

From there, it's really easy to proceed:

```
def opts(s):
    items = map(lambda x: x.strip(), my_split(s, ','))

    # collect
    ls = []
    kw = {}
    for item in items:
        if '=' in item:
            k, v = item.split('=', 1)
            kw[k.strip()] = v.strip()
        else:
            ls.append(item)

    return ls, kw
```

It's not perfect, there are still a few thing you might need to work on, but that's definetly a start.

Comment: With the addition of `.strip(' "')` to strip quotes, this produces all the test cases.  Also `flag = not flag` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where I massage the input so it matches the syntax requirements for python function arguments, then harness the python interpreter via eval to parse them.

```
import re
s = 'hog, "cog" , dog, bog, "big fish", eats="any, but peas", flies = "no!" '

# I think this will add quotes around any unquoted positional arguments
s = re.sub('(^|,)\ *([^\"\',\ ]+)\ *(?=,|$)', r'\1"\2"', s)

def f(*args, **kwargs):
    return (args, kwargs)

print eval("f("+s+")", {'f':f})
```

output:

```
(('hog', 'cog', 'dog', 'bog', 'big fish'), {'flies': 'no!', 'eats': 'any, but peas'})
```

Comment: Note that this requires that keyword arguments are quoted like (`eats="any, but peas"`, not like `eats=any, but peas`).

Comment: Added a fix so it handles spacing to spec.

Comment: I admit that this is a bit evil :-). I would not have thought of this use of `eval`. The regex preprocessing is also what I did not think of. And `'f`:f` is a nasty trick. I extended your suggestion to http://pastebin.com/HaNqEq5S, mainly to another preprocessing and more verbose variable names